# Unable to find option valid oauth redirect urls in facebook SDK Manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I 'm using Facebook SDK. But I am not able to find option valid oauth redirect urls. In Security section of advanced menu there is no option available to enable or disable oauth authentication. Please refer following image
[image: No Option to Add Redirect url]

Because I am getting an error:

[image]

Am I missing some other settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched a little and found that they have changed layout of the facebook SDK Manager. We need to add new product called Facebook Login in it.

[image]

Comment: a half a day it took me, until I read your post, thank you ! it's like all docs in the world are out-dated and it drives me crazy